# How to type annotate a main python function that return nothing

Tags: python, types

I usually use at the end of a Python script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What it the correct way to type this ?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Main does not return anything

Comment: Everything is correct there. What is the problem ?

Comment: Each function returns something, be default it is `None`. Or do you mean that `main` does not return at all, because it contains an infinite loop and any command after `main()` would be unreachable?

Comment: I'm exepecting something like `from typing import NoReturn` and `def main( -> NoReturn)`